# node.js - mocking modules with jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write some unit tests for my server side logic that is written using `node.js` framework. I wanted to use `jasmine` library for unit testing and mocking because I am a bit familiar with it.

Now, I tried something like this to mock file system `read` function:

```
'use strict';
var loginRedirectMiddleware = require('../server/loginRedirectMiddleware');
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('../server/util');

describe('loginRedirectMiddleware', function(){
  spyOn(fs,'read');
...
});
```

now I am getting an error on the line with `spyOn` invocation:

```
  1) loginRedirectMiddleware encountered a declaration exception
   Message:
     TypeError: Cannot call method 'spyOn' of null
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Cannot call method 'spyOn' of null
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/server_test/loginRedirectMiddlewareSpec.js:11:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/server_test/loginRedirectMiddlewareSpec.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/karma/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:211:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.jasmine.executeSpecsInFolder (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt-jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/index.js:151:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt-jasmine-node/tasks/jasmine-node-task.js:110:19)
    at Object.thisTask.fn (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:78:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:282:30)
    at Task.runTaskFn (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:235:24)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:281:12)
    at Task.start (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:290:5)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:155:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/home/adebksi/Nauka/js-linkedin-connector/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adebksi/.nvm/v0.10.15/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:41:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

When I do `console.log(typeof fs.read)` I am getting `function` so this property is a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it turns out it was my fault, I tried to create spy in `describe` function, I should put it for example in `it`.